# Emacs: how do I replace-regexp with a lisp function in a defun?

Tags: emacs, lisp

For example I want to make all text in parenthesis, (), UPCASE. It's trivial to do the following interactively:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp
replace: "(\(.+?\))"
with   : "(\,(upcase \1))"
```

Instead I want to write a `defun` which will do that:

```
(defun upcs ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char 1)
  (while (search-forward "(\\(.+?\\))" nil t) (replace-match "(\\,(upcase \\1))" t nil)))
```

but it doesn't work! While the following works (it appends `foo` and `bar` to the parenthesized texts):

```
(defun HOOK ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char 1)
  (while (search-forward-regexp "(\\(.+?\\))" nil t) (replace-match "(foo \\1 bar)" t nil)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this solves the problem.

```
(defun put-in-par (str)
  (concat "(" str ")"))

(defun upcs-luke ()
    (interactive)
    (goto-char 1)
        (while (search-forward-regexp "(\\([^\\)]+\\))" nil t) 
            (replace-match (put-in-par (upcase (match-string 1))) t nil)))
```

Thanks to BillC and Luke Girvin for help.

Comment: If you want to eliminate 'put-in-par', you could do: (defun upcs-luke ()
    (interactive)
    (goto-char 1)
        (while (search-forward-regexp "(\\([^\\)]+\\))" nil t) 
            (replace-match (concat "(" (upcase (match-string 1)) ")") t nil)))

Comment: Also using `format` for this purpose would be nicer and more flexible in more complicated cases.

Answer (score 7):

Luke's answer almost does the job but not quite. The original poster wanted all the text that was enclosed in parenthesis converted to upper case while Luke's code converts the code to upper case AND ALSO removes the parenthesis. A slight modification to the regex provides the correct solution:

```
(defun upcs ()
(interactive)
(goto-char 1)
    (while (search-forward-regexp "\\([^\\)]+\\)" nil t) 
        (replace-match (upcase (match-string 1)) t nil)))
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. You right - Luke's answer leaves matched-string un-braced. Your answer, though, makes all the text of the buffer upper case. I've written a simple defun - and it braces Luke's answer. I'll put the final solution as an "answer to your question". Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, my code strips off the parentheses. I won't bother editing my answer as the OP has posted the correct solution.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you're using `search-forward` in your first function. This takes a string literal rather than a regular expression. You should be using `search-forward-regexp`, as you do in your second function.

Secondly, while this code is valid as a replace value for `query-replace-regexp`, I don't think you can pass it to `replace-match`:

`(\\,(upcase \\1))`

You can get the value of the match found by `search-forward-regexp` using the `match-string` function.

Finally, I'm not sure your search regular expression is correct.

I think you need something along these lines:

```
(defun upcs ()
    (interactive)
    (goto-char 1)
        (while (search-forward-regexp "(\\([^\\)]+\\))" nil t) 
            (replace-match (upcase (match-string 1)) t nil)))
```

Comment: Thanks Luke. This actually leaves matched-string un-braced. But knowing the correct exression for string-match - it's easy to write a defun which will put it in braces. I'll post it as an "answer to your question". Thanks again.

Comment: Note: if you try this in interactive replace regex functions, `case-replace` needs to be `nil` to allow replacements to change the case. By default, it's `t` and forbids case changes.

Answer (score 3):

This was very useful, thanks all.

In the interest of putting more examples on the web, I went from this:

```
(replace-regexp "\([\%\)\”\"]\..?\)[0-9]+" "\1")
```

(which didn't work, but which used the regexps that did work in interactive mode)

to this:

```
(while (re-search-forward "\\([\\%\\\"\\”]\\)\\.?[0-9]+" nil t)
    (replace-match (match-string 1) t nil))
```

I needed three backslashes before the internal quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

The interactive regex-based replacement functions cannot change the case but otherwise work fine by default: the `case-replace` variable needs to be set to `nil` (default: `t`). Then interactive replacements then will properly  work with `,(upcase \1)`  and friends.

Reference: See discussion on the emacs-berlin mailing list: https://mailb.org/pipermail/emacs-berlin/2021/000840.html